# execute a function every minutes for 1 hour

Tags: python

I am trying to execute a function every 1 minute and end the function once reaches one hour. My function will print the current time stamp every 1 minutes untill 1 hour from when i started.

**My function:**

```
import datetime
def funcprint():
    ct = datetime.datetime.now()
    print("After 1 minute:-", ct)
    return
```

**Loop funtion I tried:** Confused on how to provide the interval of 1 minute and execute function

```
import time
delay = 60*60 # For 1 hour
close_time = time.time()+delay
while True:
    if time.time() > close_time:
        break
    else:
        funcprint() #Not sure how to interval and print for every minute
```

Comment: if you have fast function then you could use `time.sleep(60)` to sleep 60 seconds (1 minute)

Comment: shorter `while time.time() < close_time:` without `if/else`

Comment: python has standard module [sched](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html) for event scheduler. There is also external module [Advanced Python Scheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/userguide.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Code:

```
delay = 60  # 1 minute in seconds
close_time = time.time() + 60 * 60  # 1 hour later

while time.time() < close_time:  # close after 1 hour later
    funcprint()
    time.sleep(delay)  # wait in 1 minute interval
```

**EDIT:**

If the function takes more time (e.g. 2-3 secs), calculate the remaining time.

Code:

```
interval = 60  # 1 minute in seconds
close_time = time.time() + 60 * 60  # 1 hour later

while time.time() < close_time: # close after 1 hour later
    start_time = time.time()
    funcprint()
    elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time

    remaining_time = max(0, interval - elapsed_time) # dynamically adjusting according to execution time
    time.sleep(remaining_time)
```

Output:

```
After 1 minute:- 2023-11-22 16:21:32.761715
After 1 minute:- 2023-11-22 16:22:32.777379
After 1 minute:- 2023-11-22 16:23:32.799795
After 1 minute:- 2023-11-22 16:24:32.807039
After 1 minute:- 2023-11-22 16:25:32.815058
After 1 minute:- 2023-11-22 16:26:32.830860
After 1 minute:- 2023-11-22 16:27:32.840978
```

**EDIT2:**

To avoid drift in milliseconds, start_time carried out of the loop:

Code:

```
interval = 60  # 1 minute in seconds
close_time = time.time() + 60 * 60  # 1 hour later

next_start_time = time.time()     # to avoid drift in seconds

while time.time() < close_time: # close after 1 hour later
    funcprint()

    next_start_time += interval
    remaining_time = max(0, next_start_time - time.time()) # dynamically adjusting according to execution time

    time.sleep(remaining_time)
```

Output (running multiple times to view milliseconds drift, more stable than previous one):

```
After 1 minute:- 2023-11-22 16:18:31.405631
After 1 minute:- 2023-11-22 16:19:31.408488
After 1 minute:- 2023-11-22 16:21:31.415470
After 1 minute:- 2023-11-22 16:22:31.409010
After 1 minute:- 2023-11-22 16:23:31.411131
After 1 minute:- 2023-11-22 16:24:31.414009
After 1 minute:- 2023-11-22 16:25:31.415057
```

Comment: What if the function takes 2s to run? It will execute every 62s instead. Better calculate the delay each time, so as to elapse 60s after a start time.

Comment: @MatBailie I updated the post (after edit), thanks.

Comment: Start with `start_time = time.time()` (before the loop), then add 60s to that start time every iteration. That avoids all drift.

Comment: @MatBailie updated (after edit 2), and outputs were also added to see difference, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is another variant solution.
Solution use builtin library datetime and they class timedelta to calculate hours and minutes.
This variant more readble.

```py
    import time
    from datetime import datetime, timedelta
    next_start = datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=1)
    stop = datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=1)

    while datetime.now() < stop:
        print('every 5 second check')
        if datetime.now() > next_start:
            print('start func every 1 minute')
            next_start = datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=1)
        time.sleep(5)
```

more simple

```py
    import time
    from datetime import datetime, timedelta

    stop = datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=1)

    while datetime.now() < stop:
        print('start func every 1 minute')
        time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: you should describe solution.

Comment: added =) this my first solution... at stackoverflow...

Comment: Checking every 5s as to whether a minute has passed is called a "busy wait" and is a bad idea.

Comment: add, with out "busy wait"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're interested in executing a function every minute for an hour and handling potential drift in execution time.

Here's an updated code:

```py
import time
import datetime

def funcprint():
    ct = datetime.datetime.now()
    print("After 1 minute:", ct)
    return

interval = 60  # 1 minute in seconds
close_time = time.time() + 60 * 60  # 1 hour later
next_start_time = time.time()

while time.time() < close_time:  # close after 1 hour later
    funcprint()

    next_start_time += interval
    remaining_time = max(0, next_start_time - time.time())  

    time.sleep(remaining_time)

print("Execution completed after 1 hour.")
```

Output:

```
After 1 minute: 2023-12-18 18:28:32.872504
After 1 minute: 2023-12-18 18:29:32.874971
After 1 minute: 2023-12-18 18:30:32.876673
After 1 minute: 2023-12-18 18:31:32.878479
After 1 minute: 2023-12-18 18:32:32.880180
After 1 minute: 2023-12-18 18:33:32.881838
...
Execution completed after 1 hour.
```